# position fixed is not working

Tags: html, css

I have the following html...

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

And following css...

```
.header{
position: fixed;
background-color: #f00;
height: 100px;
}
.main{
background-color: #ff0;
height: 700px;
}
.footer{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
background-color: #f0f;
height: 120px;}
```

But why the header and footer is not fixed, anything I did wrong? I want only "main" to be scrollable and "header" and "footer" to be at a fixed position. How to do?

```
+-------------------------------------+
|     header                          |  -> at fixed position (top of window)
+-------------------------------------+
|       main                          |
|                                     |
|                                     | -> scrollable as its contents
|                                     |    scroll bar is window scroll bar not of main
|                                     |
|                                     |
+-------------------------------------+
|         footer                      |  -> at fixed position (bottom of window)
+-------------------------------------+
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BrmGr/)

Comment: **IE6**? What's that? (_maybe_ using tables would help).

Comment: IE6 understand position properties, but you must just use one. For example, `left`, or `right`, is fine in IE6, but if you use both of them, it doesn't understand.

Comment: @NOX I believe IE6 did not understand "position: fixed" as documented on MDN. See my answer below.

Comment: What about top and left together @NOX ?

Comment: @DavidGilbertson Yes, you are exactly right.

Comment: @sheriffderek `top` and `left` is fine. Using both `left` and `right`, and, `top` and `bottom` is not working only. If you choose just one from (left/right) and one from (top/bottom) it works correctly.

Comment: basically @C-link here is one of the less than 1% of people in the western hemisphere who have IE 6 - I guessing AOL is the ISP too -

Comment: http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Comment: @NOX Great! because he/she doesn't need to do that anyways! Good to know.

Comment: Do people really give a shi7 about IE6? The amount of "it won't work on IE6" comments on this site is just silly. If people are still using IE6, frankly they deserve to have the worst browsing experience.

Comment: Just add width to your header and footer divs.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

you need to give width explicitly to header and footer

```
width: 100%;
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BrmGr/10/)**

If you want the middle section not to be hidden then give `position: absolute;width: 100%;` and set `top and bottom` properties (related to header and footer heights) to it and give parent element `position: relative`. (ofcourse, remove `height: 700px;`.) and to make it scrollable, give `overflow: auto`.

Answer (score 99):

My issue was that a parent element had `transform: scale(1);` this apparently makes it impossible for any element to be `fixed` inside it. By removing that everything works normally...

It seems to be like this in all browsers I tested (Chrome, Safari) so don't know if it comes from some strange web standard.

(It's a popup that goes from `scale(0)` to `scale(1)`)

Comment: I ran into this with a transform3d

Comment: Same for `will-change: transform`

Comment: Thanks for this! That solved the issue for me as well.

Comment: @OZZIE are there any alternatives other than removing transform property from parent element. I have used it for some animations.

Comment: @LalindaSampath no, but in all cases I've had this issue I have solved it by just moving it our from the parent either manually or with javascript. In React you can use for example React portal: https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html :)

Comment: same for ```perspective```

Comment: same with `backdrop-filter`, I had it on `body`. After removing it worked.

Comment: same with `filter`

Comment: same with `container-type: inline-size;`

Comment: no, it doesnt make element not to be positioned with `fixed`, it just works differently, becouse containing block no longer tied to viewport dimensions.

Comment: same even with `transform: rotate(0deg)`

Comment: NextPerson: Same with `transform: rotate(1deg)` :P

Answer (score 54):

if a parent container contains transform this could happen. try commenting them

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Comment: Yep, that was it.

Comment: `-webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);`

This one also

Comment: transform: none; also works

Answer (score 17):

Double-check that you haven't enabled `backface-visibility` on any of the containing elements, as that will wreck `position: fixed`.  For me, I was using a CSS3 animation library...

Comment: I was using https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ >> Removed the animated class and voila!

Comment: This can also happen if you are setting any form of transform on a container element

Comment: @TroyWatt Saved my butt. Thx!

Comment: @TroyWatt Oh man, if i didn't read this it would've been a long ride to figure that out.

Comment: @TroyWatt You don't happen to know *why* that happens, do you?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister An element with transform applied creates a new layout context for all of it’s children. This answer provides a good explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/28157774/811533

Comment: @TroyWatt Thank you kind sir for restoring my sanity after hours of frustration!

Comment: in addition to `transform`, a container with `perspective` causes a similar issue

Comment: For me it was "filter: blur(1px)" on body. It worked after removing it.

Answer (score 9):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BrmGr/1/)**

When you are working with `fixed` or `absolute` values,
it's good idea to set `top` or `bottom` and `left` or `right` (or combination of them) properties.

Also don't set the `height` of `main` element (let browser set the height of it with setting `top` and `bottom` properties).

```
.header{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #f00;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.main{
    background-color: #ff0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 120px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #f0f;
    height: 120px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem caused by the addition of a CSS value for perspective in the body CSS

```
body { perspective: 1200px; }
```

Killed

```
#mainNav { position: fixed; }
```

Comment: Man... this kills me. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 7):

As others pointed out, certain CSS properties on a parent element will prevent `position: fixed` from working. In my case it was `backdrop-filter`.

Answer (score 5):

This might be an old topic but in my case it was the `layout` value of css `contain` property of the parent element that was causing the issue. I am using a framework for hybrid mobile that use this `contain` property in most of their component.

For example:

```
.parentEl {
    contain: size style layout;
}
.parentEl .childEl {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Just remove the `layout` value of `contain` property and the fixed content should work!

```
.parentEl {
    contain: size style;
}
```

Comment: For me, `contain: 'paint'` was the culprit

Answer (score 4):

For anyone having this issue primarily with navbars, not sticking to the top, I found that if any element in the parent container of the `positon: fixed;` element has a width exceeding 100% - so creating horizontal scrollbars - is the issue.

To solve it set the 'parent element' to have `overflow-x: hidden;`

Answer (score 3):

Another cause could be a parent container that contains the CSS `animation` property. That's what it was for me.

Answer (score 2):

You have no width set and there is not content in the divs is one issue. The other is that the way html works... when all three of fixed, is that the hierarchy goes from bottom to top... so the content is on top of the header since they are both fixed... so in this case you need to declare a z-index on the header... but I wouldn't do that... leave that one relative so it can scroll normally.

Go mobile first on this...  [FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/P34DP/)

HTML

```
<header class="global-header">HEADER</header>

<section class="main-content">CONTENT</section>

<footer class="global-footer">FOOTER</footer>
```

CSS
    html, body {
        padding: 0; margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }

```
.global-header {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    min-height: 5em;
    background-color: red;
}

.main-content {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    height: 50em;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.global-footer {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    min-height: 5em;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

@media (min-width: 30em) {

    .global-header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    .main-content {
        height: 100%;
        margin-top: 5em; /* to offset header */
    }

    .global-footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

} /* ================== */
```

Comment: If you declare the main content fixed, it will not scroll by default (as the window normally would) - add a margin or padding top to it as position relative to offset the fixed header.

Comment: You can add a conditional hack to the header of your html with style specifically for IE 6 and & where you position the divs absolute or relative or whatever. Seriously, your fixed header and footer aren't the key points to your website - and you shouldn't even have them on smaller screen devices as it will take up needed space, and even iOS doen't handle fixed properly yet... so... yeah...

Comment: I'm starting to think that I should explain that you need to drag your browser.. or the iframe in the fiddle I made for you.. larger and smaller to actually understand what is happening.

Comment: as long as you don't use relative on a larger container...  you could use absolute to the window for the header as well... what a mess.

Comment: Yeah. This has been solved in more than one way already in this post.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the width of the two divs.

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    background-color: #f00;
    height: 100px; width: 100%;
}
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #f0f;
    height: 120px; width:100%;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tomer123/BrmGr/9/)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't add any width or content to the elements. Also you should set padding top and bottom to your main element so the content is not hidden behind the header/footer. You can remove the height as well and let the browser decide based on the content.

http://jsfiddle.net/BrmGr/12/

```
.header{
position: fixed;
background-color: #f00;
height: 100px;
    width:100%;
}
.main{
background-color: #ff0;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 120px;
}
.footer{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
background-color: #f0f;
height: 120px;
    width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, my parent was set to transform-style: preserve-3d; removing it did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

We'll never convince people to leave IE6 if we keep striving to deliver quality websites to those users.

Only IE7+ understood "position: fixed".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

So you're out of luck for IE6. To get the footer semi-sticky try this:

```
.main {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -60px;
}
.footer {
  height: 60px;
}
```

You could also use an iFrame maybe.

This will keep the footer from 'lifting off' from the bottom of the page. If you have more than one page of content then it will push down out of site.

On a philosophical note, I'd rather point IE6 users to http://browsehappy.com/ and spend the time I save hacking for IE6 on something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in the same way because if the parent container has the transform effect, you could create a child where it occupies 100% of the parent container and add a position realtive and then the container that you want to add the position fixed and it works without problems.

Answer (score 0):

might be an answer for some cases https://stackoverflow.com/a/75284271/7874122

TLDR `position: fixed` is attached to containing element, by which element is positioned. if containing block is different than viewport dimensions, `fixed` element will be placed according to containing block.