# why -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) messes up with fixed childs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transforms

I've been trying for the last few hours to figure out how come a child element was positioning against its parent and not the screenport even though it's positioned as 'fixed'. Very luckily, I stumbled across the mentioning that `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)` on the parent can make things go awry. I'm using `bootstrap` framework and so they indeed put this property on the `.navbar-fixed-top` class which one of parent elements had. Once I removed it the child started to position agains viewport. So I have two questions:

1. Why does `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)` do these nasty things?
2. Why do bootstrap guys put this property for the `.navbar-fixed-top` class?

**UPDATE**
Well, it seems that I've found the answer to the second question. Here is the commit message:

> Applied translate3d to modal, navbar-fixed and affix to combat browser
>   repaint

Here is the answer to the second question:

> Any computed value other than none for the transform results in the
>   creation of both a stacking context and a containing block. The object
>   acts as a containing block for fixed positioned descendants.

Comment: The short answer is stacking contexts - google that and you'll get some good (long) explanations

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Regarding your first question:

You are using transforms. That's what's causing the problem.

Take a look at the spec: [The Transform Rendering Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-rendering)

> Specifying a value other than ‘none’ for the ‘transform’ property
>   establishes a new local coordinate system at the element that it is
>   applied to.

So the element with fixed positioning will become relative to the element with the transform - not the viewport

Answer (score 1):

I used this "hackery"(-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)) to fix glitches from transform scale (some elements where moving as I was interacting  with the page ) but I had an  issue with position fixed on webkit(I couldn't set focus on fixed positioned text inputs) and when I removed it it was fixed.As I was using transform scale only on firefox there was no problem for me to remove it(On webkit I ended up using zoom which acts much better than transform:scale(but -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) was left there from legacy css) and I hope that firefox supported zoom as well)

Answer (score 1):

According to [mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) **fixed** position is removed from normal document flow and attached to **containing block**.

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to the **initial containing block** established by the viewport, except when one of its ancestors has a transform, perspective, or filter property set to something other than none (see the CSS Transforms Spec), or the will-change property is set to transform, in which case that ancestor behaves as the containing block.

Element [containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#identifying_the_containing_block) regarding mdn documentation is:

- if element position is `fixed` containing block is `initial containing block` that has viewport dimensions.
- Or containing block can be set by specific css properties `transform, perspective, will-change, filter, contain, backdrop-filter` in this case element is positioned regarding specified element

in this case `transform` property mentioned in question creates containing block by which `fixed` element is positioned.