# TinyMCE cannot be full screen when placed in Bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tinymce

I try to make the TinyMCE editor to appear inside a modal but i can't make it fullscreen.
Here's a jsfiddle, if you resize it the fullscreen covers up the area the modal would cover.
http://jsfiddle.net/344y9brr/

```
Full screen is under View -> Fullscreen
```

Comment: the problem seems to be with the modal not going full width when the browser is in full screen mode... interesting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18522320/1861459

Comment: pherris , no, this makes the modal full window (and in turn the things inside the modal , tinymce in this case, fullscreen. I want a regular modal and the tinymce button will make it fullscreen)

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to make tinymce full screen without it covering the modal window. Maybe I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: The tinymce has a fullscreen function (found inside View->fullscreen). But it won't cover the full screen width,height it will cover the width the height the modal takes up. If i move the html code outside of modal it will cover everything.

Answer (score 5):

When an element inside the modal dialog has position:fixed, the transforms affect the calculation of the element's position. This creates a problem when **tinymce** is viewed *fullscreen*.

Change **transform: translate(0, 0);** to the following in your style sheet:

```
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: none;
      -ms-transform: none;
       -o-transform: none;
          transform: none;
}
```

Updated fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/344y9brr/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/344y9brr/4/)

The **transform: translate(0, 0);** creates a containing block for fixed-position descendants. See this question [why -webkit-transform messes up with fixed childs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824749/why-webkit-transform-translate3d0-0-0-messes-up-with-fixed-childs) for more info.

Comment: @Abdo-Host, click the expand button -- editor expands to fit the screen. What's not working for you?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to change original CSS of `.modal-dialog`, do this when init tinymce:

```
setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('FullscreenStateChanged', function (e) {
        if (e.state) {
            $('.modal-dialog').attr('style', 'transform: none !important');
        } else {
            $('.modal-dialog').attr('style', 'transform: translate(0,0)');
        }
    });
}
```