# Position fixed not working is working like absolute

Tags: css

my question is pretty simple. I'm working on a page on mobile version, and we want to keep the "snag it" yellow button fixed on bottom, but position fixed is not working, it's working like position absolute and i don't know why.

The page i'm working: https://www.thechivery.com/products/everything-is-j-ok-tee

Thanks,
Luiz

Comment: The use of `-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)` on the `.content-container` class throws off the `fixed` positioning context, and the positioning becomes relative to the class the transform was declared on rather than the viewport. See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824749/why-webkit-transform-translate3d0-0-0-messes-up-with-fixed-childs). Remove that rule and your fixed element will work as normal.

Comment: Here's a super simple fiddle demonstrating how the transform destroys the `fixed` positioning: https://jsfiddle.net/p7oy6fL4/

Comment: Hey man, it's exactly what you said! Don't you want to answer so i can elect your answer? Thanks!

Comment: Adding 'filter' property on the parent element also causes that.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

The issue here lies with your `.content-container` wrapper class, which has a CSS declaration of `webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)`. The transform declaration, as [this answer illustrates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824749/why-webkit-transform-translate3d0-0-0-messes-up-with-fixed-childs), changes the positioning context from the viewport to the rotated element, which essentially means that your `fixed` element behaves as if it were absolutely positioned. Here's an example showing the difference between a fixed element inside a transformed `div` and a fixed element outside of that `div`.

```css
.rotate {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  background: blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate">
  <div class="fixed"> I am fixed inside a rotated div.</div>
</div>
<div class="fixed"> I am fixed outside a rotated div.</div>
```

In order for everything to work, you'll need to remove the `transform3d` declaration from `.content-container`.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the 'perspective' property also triggers this bug. If you get this issue in future, the easiest way to diagnose is to drag the element up through each of its ancestors until it starts behaving - then look for suspect properties on the offending element.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know this was thing.... How odd.

Comment: If we don't apply that css, then elements are disappear and appear again. How to avoid this without getting this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807620/ipad-safari-scrolling-causes-html-elements-to-disappear-and-reappear-with-a-dela

Comment: `will-change` appears to have the same effect of changing the context.

Comment: @DanEastwell Correct, `will-change` creates [a stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) just like `transform` does.

Comment: -webkit-overflow-scrolling in the parent element also causes this problem

Comment: Just to clarify, you *can* use `transform` on the own element. That bug affects when using `transform` (or the other attributes pointed) on the *parent* (in any level) element.

Comment: Very smart analysis, thanks @Maximilian
I encountered same problem within a transform: translateX() container. I could set a workaround based on position: relative + left properties

Comment: `filter` also causes this problem, so check the element's ancestors for `filter`.

Comment: Was stuck on this issue for ages with CodeMirror autocompletion not showing

Comment: I just have 1 hair left on my head ...

Comment: In my case, it was caused by `contain: strict` on one of the containers.

Answer (score 14):

For anyone wondering if this is a browser bug. Apparently it's not and it follows current W3C specs. What's strange is at first it was just inconsistent between the browsers (in some it worked as intended) and then all of them started to follow the counter intuitive W3C rules. There seems to be no clear explanation if this is actually intended logic, a side effect of some implementation problem or just a dumb omission.

Also `position: fixed` gets broken not only by `transform` but also by `filter` and `perspective` property put on any ancestor as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

See: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#propdef-transform and
https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=16328 and https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/913 for more info on this issue.

Comment: Just wanted to add: ```backdrop-filter``` property on an ancestor also messes up the ```position: fixed```

Comment: for me too it was the backdrop-filter

Comment: Yes, `backdrop-filter` for me removed `backdrop-filter` from parent `node` worked.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was caused by mixing a css `transform` with `overflow: auto;` on the parent.

I created a new child element on which I moved the `overflow` property.

Separating the two properties fixed the issue.

Answer (score -3):

It's a mobile specific issue. I have encountered this issue before. Generally speaking mobile browsers, particularly older ones, restrict the use of fixed positioning because it can take up too much room on the screen.

http://bradfrost.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/

Comment: I got this issue using Google Chrome on device emulation mode for iPhone 6 (it happens with all other devices on google chrome too), but thanks, i'll check this link!

Comment: The article referred to was posted in 2011. Even when this answer was posted in 2016 it was outdated. Yes there are still mobile browsers out there that can't handle it (very old and Opera Mini in particular) but Opera Mini and other such users must be used to a pretty broken experience on the wild web. Check out caniuse.com for current (and historic, to some extent) situation.

Comment: i don't know why you got so down voted. my "high-tech" iPhone + last iOS chrome can't handle a `position:fixed;` properly and i'm looking for solution everywhere, nothing solid found. Yes we are in 2018.