# Browser Zoom level alters measured pixel location vs MouseEvent.clientX report

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I'm trying to get the coordinates of a click event in chrome. The event is generated using `onClick` handler of a ReactComponent like so:

```
<img
    onClick={(e) => { console.log('e:', e.clientX, window.scrollX, "pageX", e.pageX);}}
</img>
```

[image]

The resulting value:

[image]

Clearly does not match the value as measured by a ruler. This is also manifested when I try and add a div at the position of the click. It doesn't appear at the correct position, but rather at an offset.

Has anybody encountered a similar situation?

Comment: What about trying `e.pageX` ?

Comment: It's the same as `e.clientX`. I updated the question.

Comment: The `clientX` value is correct, but that is not what you need:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX

Comment: `The MouseEvent.clientX read-only property provides the horizontal coordinate within the application's client area at which the event occurred` - Isn't the application's client area the area within the browser that is visible at the moment? The ruler spans the width of the browser.

Comment: The diffrence between `clientX` and `offsetX` is tied to the CSS, margins and padding ...

Comment: Right, but shouldn't `clientX` be relative to the edge of the browser window?

Comment: Nope, `pageX`would. Please read the MDN articles I've linked above.

Comment: Sorry, I've read the articles and I don't mean to be obtuse, but in this case `clientX` is equal to `pageX` and neither corresponds to the distance from the click event to the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

Browser window was zoomed in. `Cmd - [minus]` fixed the event position relative to the ruler. The `div` positioning was related to the issue described here:

[Position fixed not working is working like absolute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36855473/position-fixed-not-working-is-working-like-absolute)