# iPad Safari elements disappear and reappear with a delay

Tags: ios, css, ipad, scroll, mobile-safari

For this bug I have referred the below stack overflow question and have applied in the css as follows (Refer: 
[iPad Safari scrolling causes HTML elements to disappear and reappear with a delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807620/ipad-safari-scrolling-causes-html-elements-to-disappear-and-reappear-with-a-dela))

```
*:not(html) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

**After applying, I am facing a new issue. That is if I apply fixed position for an element, that's not fixed in the browser top instead of scrolling.**

***If I remove the above css, It is working fine.*** (Refer: [Position fixed not working is working like absolute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36855473/position-fixed-not-working-is-working-like-absolute))

How to fix the issue without affecting the fixed element?

Comment: Can you please add some of your actual code?

Comment: Create the code snippet with the problem, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transforms create a [new stacking order and context](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#module-interactions). That means that `fixed` positioning will no longer be tied to the viewport.

In this particular case, the simple answer is that you can't combine transforms and `fixed` positioning.

Comment: Thanks for the good info. Then how can I avoid elements reappearing in ipad without affecting the fixed elements? Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @JeevaJsb my best advice is to avoid using this hack in a blanket fashion. Don't apply it to everything. Try applying it only to the element that flickers. Otherwise, redesign your page so that you don't need this hack at all.

Comment: @SergChernata Thanks for this answer! was wondering what was going wrong in my app.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using this hack, you could try to separate fixed elements and the content, something like this:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

.content, .content * {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.content {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.content-example {
    height: 2000px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">Fixed</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="content-example"></div>
</div>
```

Without your HTML/CSS I can't say more precisely, but I recommend you to avoid using this hack and try to change your code properly.