# Why does `transform` break `position: fixed`?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Actually I have found what has caused the problem. My question is now why adding `transform` to your `html, body` breaks the `position: fixed`?

**Original problem**

The most simple CSS task seems to fail for me: `position: fixed` does not keep the position of the element relative to the view point. Consider the following stylesheet:

```css
.stay-there-dammit {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1030;
}
```

For the first time the page loads, the positioning is correct. But any changes to viewport such as scrolling or resizing doesn't affect the positioning of `.stay-there-dammit` element. So to speak it doesn't adapt its position to the new viewport.

Strangely enough [this site](http://www.3site.eu/examples/position-fixed/quirks.html) which shows how `position: fixed` should work, actually work in my browser with no problems whatsoever!

So the question is: **Is there anything that might break fixed positioning?**

Btw. I use Bootstrap 3.

**UPDATE:**

It seems that it was the transform set by some third-party application on `html,body` that broke the `position: fixed`. Here is what I had to remove:

```css
html, body {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3, mirror=1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
     -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
       -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
          transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

It seems that the following question addresses the same issue:

[Positions fixed doesn't work when using -webkit-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637058/positions-fixed-doesnt-work-when-using-webkit-transform)

**BUT WHY?**

Comment: works fine for me, post a jsfiddle

Comment: A jsfiddle would work @DavidXu! The question is if there is anything on my page that might break it. The page is fairly loaded with CSS and I couldn't possibly paste/mock it in a single jsfiddle!

Comment: You need to post an example which demonstrates the problem if you’d like an answer for this.

Comment: @Zaqx if I could then I would! The question is if there are any known issues that might break the styling.

Comment: @DavidXu thanks but if you are not aware of any known issues that might break the styling I'll for someone else to show up. And I wouldn't possibly be able to give you a link to the company's website.

Comment: When u use fixed the `<div>` doesnt move on Scrolling use `position:absolute` instead

Comment: @j_s_stack `position: absolute` is not relative to viewport.

Comment: Can you Link your site?

Comment: @t.niesse actually I just have it under `body` and the body has no stylings.

Comment: @t.niesse have found the problem. Cannot figure out why it has caused it!

Comment: @YanFoto you have found the answer to your original question, you should update the question title and the question if you are now asking why

Comment: @YanFoto in the question you linked, the answer says it's a webkit bug

Comment: @Huangism I have it both in FireFox and Chrome!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Regarding the ***why***, a quick quote from this [article](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/09/12/un-fixing-fixed-elements-with-css-transforms/) by meyer:

> A transformed element creates a containing block even for descendants that have been set to position: fixed.  In other words, the containing block for a fixed-position descendant of a transformed element is the transformed element, not the viewport

It's a quirky behavior that's been around since 2011.

Comment: Thanks. Finally someone who read the **bold** question without getting annoyed or offended by the rest!

Comment: Here's the relevant [part on w3.org Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering) and [here's the issue on Chromium bug tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20574&desc=2), even though - as correctly pointed out in this answer - it's not a bug but a quirky behaviour