# Stop overlapping when position fixed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to prevent the left div from scrolling. I've set its position to fixed but now, it is overlapping with the right one. What can I do? I've tried position: relative and absolute to the right div but nothing happens.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
           <div id="googleMap"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your css ? nothing here shows your issue. tip: take a look at position:sticky and polyfills avalable

Comment: `position: sticky` is still very unsupported, [http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky), thus the recommendation for polyfills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the class `col-sm-offset-7` to the `col-sm-5` element.

When you make an element's position `absolute` or `fixed`, it is removed from the flow of `relative` and `static` elements, thus vacating its space in that flow, allowing subsequent elements to "move up" (or left in your situation) in its place.

Assuming you're using Bootstrap, your `col` divs are floated left so when you make the `col-sm-7` fixed, it gets pulled out of the flow making the `col-sm-5` float all the way to the left where the other element used to be before being removed from the flow.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my overlapping problem, but I still can prevent it it  from scrolling..

Comment: So, the element you applied a `fixed` position to still scrolls with the site?

Comment: I would guess the fixed element has a parent with a transform applied to it. [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28157125/why-does-transform-break-position-fixed)