# Angular2: set md-fab button 'position: fixed' in inner component

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

I use the md-fab-button from the original angular2 material-framework.
I want to set the md-fab-button(for adding a new entity) `position: fixed` but I want to place the button in an inner component inside the `md-sidenav-layout` but if I do so then the `position: fixed` doesn't work.

The code above:

```
<div class="{{themeService.ActualTheme}}">
    <md-sidenav-layout class="full-height" fullscreen>
```

This class attribute is just for theming the app
I also tried it without fullscreen and set with the class "full-height" the `md-sidenav-layout` to 100% height and absolute, but it doesn't work.

First try(`position: fixed` doesn't work):

```
        <button (click)="onPlusClickAction()" class="add-group-button" color="accent" md-fab>
            <md-icon class="md-24 plus-icon">add</md-icon>
        </button>

    </md-sidenav-layout>
</div>
```

Instead of the `router-outlet` the inner component will be replaced(standard angular2 routing).

Now I tried to put the md-fab-button here:

```
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    </md-sidenav-layout>

    <button (click)="onPlusClickAction()" class="add-group-button" color="accent" md-fab>
        <md-icon class="md-24 plus-icon">add</md-icon>
    </button>
</div>
```

If I do so, then the `position: fixed` works, but now the md-fab-button is outside of the `md-sidenav-layout` and always when I open my sidenav, the fab-button lays over the sidenav. `z-index` doesn't work because then the fab-button disappears completly.

Has anyone a good idea to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The fixed position does not work because there is a `transform: translate3d` CSS attribute set on the `md-sidenav-layout` element. In such cases

> the object will act as a containing block for position: fixed elements
>   that it contains

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

There is already an open issue on the Material 2 project requesting to remove the `translate3d` value from `sidenav`, but so far the Material team did not address the issue: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/998

I faced the same situation and solved it with a quite heavy workaround. I removed the FAB from the main content, defined a secondary router outlet in my template (outside md-sidenav-layout), created a standalone component for the FAB, and used an Observable in a service to broadcast the click events to the main components.

**Layout**

```
<md-sidenav-container>
    <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" class="app-sidenav">
        <md-nav-list>
            <a md-list-item routerLink="/">
                <span md-line>Home</span>
            </a>
    </md-nav-list>
  </md-sidenav>
    <md-toolbar color="primary">
        <button md-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
            <md-icon class="icon-40">menu</md-icon>
        </button>
        <span>Angular Material 2 Sidenav with FAB</span>
    </md-toolbar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</md-sidenav-container>
<router-outlet name="fab"></router-outlet>
```

**FAB service**

```
export class FabService {

  private actionSource = new Subject<string>();
  public actionStream = this.actionSource.asObservable();

  public broadcastAction(action: string) {
      this.actionSource.next(action);
  }
}
```

**FAB component**

```
@Component({
    template: '<button md-fab class="fab" (click)="actionHandler()"><md-icon>add</md-icon></button>',
    styles: [`
        button.fab {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 12px;
            right: 12px;
        }
    `]
})
export class FabComponent {

    constructor(private fabService: FabService) { }

    actionHandler() {
        this.fabService.broadcastAction('click');
    }  
}
```

**Main component**

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private fabService: FabService)  { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.fabService.actionStream.subscribe(event => this.events.push(event));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }  
}
```

**And the routing**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', children: [
        { path: '', component: MainComponent},
        { path: '', component: FabComponent, outlet: 'fab' }
    ]}
```

Full working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/GLFWfdy2JSXNKefhuNLA?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. After a huge research, I found two good solutions:

**Option 1:**

You can add `display: flex` property to the `md-sidenav` component and to the `md-sidenav-content`. Please check the following working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/VItn3Y2AaTzpzIykTTyH?p=preview

**Option 2:**

As @András Szepesházi said the main problem is coming from the `transform: translate3d` property, so the easiest solution is to remove it:

```
.md-sidenav-content {
    transform: none !important;
}
```

**NOTE:** please check what exactly `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` is doing. Here is a good SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18529444/2765346

Comment: Helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: In version 2.0.0-beta.10 works this: `.mat-drawer-content {
    transform: none !important;
}`