# How do you make an HTML tooltip fully visible in an overflow:hidden parent?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a tooltip for my application so that when i hover over some writing, a popup appears. The writing that is to be hovered over is not fully visible (ie it is in a table cell with overflow:hidden so the words cut off). I want to display the full writing in a tooltip when hovering over it. I want the tooltip to be fully visible, unaffected by the overflow:hidden of the table cell. Here is what I have so far:

CSS:

```
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
}

.tooltip:hover:after {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    color: #fff;
    top: -30px;
    left: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    content: attr(alt);
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="overflow:hidden">
            <span alt="reallyLongFullWriting" class="tooltip">partiallyHiddenWriting</span>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It works like this but the tooltip gets hidden when it overflows as well. Please help me figure out how to make the tooltip fully visible and not partially hidden. Thanks.

Edit:
Here is a photo of what seems to be happening:

[image]

Comment: Does changing the z-index css property not help?

Comment: unfortunately it does not seem to help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you will keep the same structure you cannot make the element visible with `overflow:hidden`.

A solution is to specify a height/width on the `td` element to create the necessary space for the `:after` element.

```css
table {
  margin: 50px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
}

td {
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border:1px solid;
}

.tooltip:hover:after {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  color: #fff;
  top: -30px;
  left: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  content: attr(alt);
  padding: 5px 15px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span alt="fullWriting" class="tooltip">partiallyHiddenWriting</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Another alternative is to use fixed position **BUT** without changing top/left/right/bottom property to keep the tooltip relative to its initial position. Instead adjust the position with some negative margin.

*This solution will not work if you have scrolling in your page so it's not a generic solution. because **an element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled.***

```css
table {
  margin: 50px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
}

td {
  overflow: hidden;
  border:1px solid;
}

.tooltip:hover:after {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  color: #fff;
  margin-top:-30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  content: attr(alt);
  padding: 5px 15px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index:999;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span alt="fullWriting" class="tooltip">partiallyHiddenWriting</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

A workaround to still be able to use fixed position on scrollable page is to apply a transform with no effect on a parent element:

```css
body {
 min-height:120vh;
}

table {
  margin: 50px;
  transform:translate(0,0);
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
}

td {
  overflow: hidden;
  border:1px solid;
}

.tooltip:hover:after {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  color: #fff;
  margin-top:-30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  content: attr(alt);
  padding: 5px 15px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index:999;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span alt="fullWriting" class="tooltip">partiallyHiddenWriting</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Some usefull links to understand the effect of transform on fixed position :

[Why does `transform` break `position: fixed`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28157125/why-does-transform-break-position-fixed)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37953806/8620333

Comment: Unfortunately it is not the height that is giving me issues. It is the width that is giving more trouble. I cant make the width of the cell any larger because of the other data going into the table

Comment: @ALec but the tooltip is place on the top, so the width should not provide you any issue .. or maybe you can share with us a more compete code to see :)

Comment: I have added a photo of what happens. As you can see, even though the tooltip is above the writing, it is still limited by the width of the cell and therefore gets cut off. The width seems to be my issue.

Comment: @ALec ah ok! it's the width of the tooltip then, not the cell

Comment: @ALec added another solution ;)

Comment: Well if I set width:1000px; it still cuts it off at the same place (right at the edge of the cell). This leads me to believe that the tooltip is inside of the cell and the cell's width is cutting off the tooltip.

Comment: @ALec try may last attempt and let me know :)

Comment: @ALec check again, added more details :)