# CSS transform: scale makes bottom fixed elements disappear

Tags: html, css, css-position, transform, scale

I'm trying to scale the elements in my body tag so that my website looks the same on differing screen sizes. However, when I apply transform: scale(), the fixed elements associated with bottom disappear. Why is this and how can I fix it?

css

```
body
{
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
}

#invite
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 31px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

The invite element disappears when I scale with 1.

Answer (score 2):

`transform:scale(0.5)` will create a new binding box for the `position:fixed;` element, (when that element is a child of the transformed item)

[relevant Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28157125/why-does-transform-break-position-fixed)
and further [explanations](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20574&desc=2) in the chromium bug tracker

Example 'buggy' behaviour:

```css
div {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.body {
  background: olive;
  min-height:600px
}

.main {
  background: pink;
}

.bottom {
  background: orange;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

.body:hover {
  transform: scale(1)
}
```

```html
<div class='body'>
  <div class="main">
    main content</div>
  <div class="bottom"> bottom content </div>;
</div>
```

As for alternatives: [responsive design](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp); the general philosophy is to re-arrange elements into a single vertical stack as the viewport gets smaller.

Comment: Could you explain how to fix it then?

Comment: I don't know what your design looks like right now. Different designs would require different approaches. The link about responsive design should point you in a general direction. 
Or is there a reason you're scaling the entire body down? instead of re-arranging. It feels to mee that on a smaller screen size, the text will become unreadable.

Comment: Uploaded some simple css code in the problem so perhaps that would help? And does adding the meta tag work for laptop/desktop screens or only for mobile devices such as tablets and phones? Also would changing bottom values from pixel to vw and vh work?

Comment: Changing from px to vh/vw will not work. As soon as there is a transform applied on a parent element, a new bounding box is calculated. So any fixed child will adhere to this new bounding box. Adding the meta tag will be helpful to differentiate between the different devices. I urge you to take a look at the media queries in [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_responsive_media_query3).  when the screenwidth goes below 620px, the page is re-arranged with different rule-set.

Comment: Just to be clear the meta tag <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> only works with mobile devices correct? It doesn't affect different laptop and desktop screen sizes?

Comment: Could I dynamically change the value 1 from initial-scale so that the content ends up smaller if the screen is smaller?

Comment: Keep in mind the `<meta name='viewport'...` is part of larger solution. you most likely need to add media queries to get it to look properly on all devices, The meta viewport allows you set a minimal size, (smaller sizes will introduces a scrollbar). It works on all devices. `width=device-width` simply means screen in portrait mode, or width is smaller then height. You can test this by setting a screen size in the browser dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

It will be more helpful if you could include your code and I think you should use `media query` if you are trying to make your page responsive.

Comment: Just uploaded some css for you.

Comment: See this documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries