# Navbar not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

i'm new to ReactJS and would like to ask..

In my website there is a problem that is when i scroll to down, My Navbar is gone,

Here is the website:
https://kramakata.netlify.app/

I still searchin for the issues, don't know what cause it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your navbar doesn't seem to be positioned as fixed `.navbar { position: fixed; }` this should solve the problem from what i understood

Comment: yeah still gone from scrolling, i don't know why it happens, it's weird

Comment: Okay i've looked into it and it is told [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879737/position-fixed-is-not-working) that if an element has a translate on it it cannot be fixed, you have a div with a `transform: translate` which is a parent of your `div#root`